# Highcharts 3.0 clip-path confusion

Tags: highcharts

If I look at the DOM element of Highcharts I do see a clippath:

```
<clipPath id="highcharts-2">
  <rect fill="none" x="0" y="0" width="796" height="367"></rect>
</clipPath>
```

and the series group referencing to it:

```
<g class="highcharts-series"..... clip-path="url(#highcharts-2)">
```

as the clip rectangle is overlapping the renderd series, shouldn't the clipPath have an effect on it? I think in previous versions it was possible to manipulate the clipPath with jQuery and show only parts of the series.

How can I

a) make this clipPath effective

b) even add my own clipPaths and animate them on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either manipulate this using jQuery, or you can use the Highcharts renderer like Highcharts does internally. This will also work with old IE browsers.

`chart.clipRect.attr({ width: 300 });`

See http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/7c8am/. You can create your own clips using Element.clip.

Comment: Let's assume I do have series group of 4 lines and wanted to control each lines visibilty/build-up with with clipRect, how would create a clipRect for each and control them?

Comment: Torstein, sorry to hijack this post but I've been working on this problem, [Changing X axis type from category to datetime on drilldown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234418/changing-x-axis-type-from-category-to-datetime-on-drilldown), for a few days and can't find any other examples online. I know you will know if this is possible, since you are the highcharts big kahuna.