# Changing X axis type from category to datetime on drilldown

Tags: php, javascript, html, highcharts

Is it possible to change a graph's x axis type from category to datetime on drilldown? I have stacked column style graph where each column is a different category. When I click on one of the columns I want to drilldown to a dedicated column graph of that category with a datetime x axis.

I have been able to successfully drilldown to another category style graph, and set each category to a day in a daterange, but using the datetime format would be much better.

Here is the "onClick" code I am running to try to do this. Obviously the data is sample data just to keep things simple. Currently, this crashes Firefox with a memory limit.

Is it even possible to switch x axis type dynamically like this?

```
function setChart() {



    while(hChart.series.length > 0){
        hChart.series[0].remove();
    }


    hChart.xAxis[0].update({
        type: 'datetime'
    });

    console.log(hChart.xAxis[0]);


    data = [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 5],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 11],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3), 3],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6), 7],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 7), 4],
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 8), 1]
    ];
    console.log(data);



    hChart.addSeries({
       type: 'column',
      data: data,
    }, false);

    hChart.redraw();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforunately this option is not avaialble, you need to destroy and create new chart.

Comment: Thanks. I'll move forward with that.

Answer (score 7):

For someone still looking for answer. The solution is:

**Define X-axis in an array**:

```
xAxis: [{
          id: 0,
          type: 'category'
        }, {
          id: 1,
          type: 'datetime'
        }]
```

**For each series in drilldown**

```
drilldown: {
          series: [{
            name: "test",
            id: "test",
            xAxis: 1, // <--- your desired X axis ID
            data: [
              [your data]
            ]
          }]
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! Note: You do not have to be explicit with the xAxis id declaration in the first block. The xAxis elements will automatically get id assignments of 0, 1, 2, etc. It's good to see the explicit correlation in the answer, I'm just adding here for anyone going for minimal code.