# How to change x-axis type from category to datetime on drilldown with Highcharter in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111310/how-to-drill-down-to-the-third-hierarchy-using-higherchart-package-in-r) I was able to learn how to make as many drill-down plots as I want.

The issue I've faced thought is that my date is seen as a "category" and not as a time-series. I would like to modify this code to display the last level (or if possible, any level I want) of a drill-down plot as a "dateTime" graph instead of a "category" graph.

I have tried using the provided code, but it only displays the last level as a "category" graph, even when my data is in "dateTime" format. Can someone please advise on how to modify the code to achieve this?

```
Test <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                             "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                   Group_Two = c("AA", "AAA", "AA", "AAA", "AAA", "AA", 
                                 "AA", "AAA", "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB", 
                                 "BB", "BBB", "BB", "BBB"),
                   Group_Three = c("AJX", "ABX", "AJX", "ABX", "APX", "ANX", 
                                   "ANX", "APX", "BJX", "BBX", "BJX", "BBX", 
                                   "BPX", "BNX", "BPX", "BNX"),
                   Group_Four = as.Date(c("2022-07-12", "2022-07-16", "2022-07-31", "2022-08-01", "2022-08-12", "2022-08-21", "2022-08-27", 
                                  "2022-09-14", "2022-09-16", "2022-09-21", "2022-11-12", "2022-11-23", "2022-12-14", "2022-12-17", 
                                  "2022-12-24", "2022-12-29")),
                   Value = c(5293, 78225, 33235, 56022, 13056, 6160, 44067, 75529, 
                             95679, 98172, 27159, 77475, 37838, 25897, 88400, 28484))

TestSum <- Test %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
  )

TestSum <- arrange(TestSum,desc(Quantity))

Lvl1dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum$Group, y = TestSum$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(name))

Level_2_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  TestSum2 <- TestSum2 %>%
    group_by(Group_Two) %>%
    summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
    )
  TestSum2 <- arrange(TestSum2,desc(Quantity)) ###CHECK
  Lvl2dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum2$Group_Two, y = TestSum2$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))
  list(id = tolower(x_level), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus))
})

Level_3_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    TestSum3 <- TestSum3 %>%
      group_by(Group_Three) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
      )
    TestSum3 <- arrange(TestSum3,desc(Quantity))
    Lvl3dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum3$Group_Three,y = TestSum3$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, name, sep = "_")))
    list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse(Lvl3dfStatus))
  })
})%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

Level_4_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    lapply(unique(TestSum3$Group_Three), function(z_level) {
      TestSum4 <- subset(TestSum3, TestSum3$Group_Three %in% z_level)
      #TestSum4 <- TestSum3[TestSum3$Group_Three == z_level,]
      TestSum4 <- TestSum4 %>%
        group_by(Group_Four) %>%
        summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
        )
      TestSum4 <- arrange(TestSum4,desc(Quantity))
      Lvl4dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum4$Group_Four,y = TestSum4$Quantity)
      list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, z_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse2(Lvl4dfStatus))
    })
  })%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
}) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = c(Level_2_Drilldowns_Test, Level_3_Drilldowns_Test, Level_4_Drilldowns)
  )
```

Thanks is advance !

Edit: in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780141/12322285), it seems that you can do it (see this example i've made: https://jsfiddle.net/scrk20wa/).
How can I implement this script in my R code?

PS: **If I may, I would like to note that my actual data consists of thousands of rows**.

Comment: Could you reproduce this problem in JS? Since I don't have that much knowledge of R but seeing this code in JS maybe I can help better. Because basically the point is that you want a drilldown demo with xAxis in datatime format, right?

Comment: Sadly, I'm currently limited in my knowledge of JS as I'm relatively new to it, but I've recently started to explore it more due to my increased usage of the "highcharter" package in R.

Comment: But I know that "highcharter" package in R is basically a translation of the JS package and If it's possible in the JS version then It can be done in the R version too.

Comment: @madepiet hello again, i was able to make a JS example of what i want : https://jsfiddle.net/scrk20wa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours learning about the `highcharter` package and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234418/changing-x-axis-type-from-category-to-datetime-on-drilldown/33780141#33780141) I managed to change the X-axis type. To achieve this, I added the `id` (Xaxis = 0 or Xaxis = 1) of the X-axis type to every level of the Drilldown as follows:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

Level_2_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  TestSum2 <- TestSum2 %>%
    group_by(Group_Two) %>%
    summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
    )
  TestSum2 <- arrange(TestSum2,desc(Quantity)) ###CHECK
  Lvl2dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum2$Group_Two, y = TestSum2$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, name, sep = "_")))
  list(id = tolower(x_level),
type = "column",
xAxis = 0, # 0 is the first type you put in the hc_xaxis argument, 1 is for the second, etc...
data = list_parse(Lvl2dfStatus))
})

Level_3_Drilldowns_Test <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    TestSum3 <- TestSum3 %>%
      group_by(Group_Three) %>%
      summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
      )
    TestSum3 <- arrange(TestSum3,desc(Quantity))
    Lvl3dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum3$Group_Three,y = TestSum3$Quantity, drilldown = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, name, sep = "_")))
    list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, sep = "_")),
type = "column",
xAxis = 0, # 0 is the first type you put in the hc_xaxis argument, 1 is for the second, etc...
data = list_parse(Lvl3dfStatus))
  })
})%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)

Level_4_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
  TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
  #TestSum2 <- Test[Test$Group == x_level,]
  lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
    TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
    #TestSum3 <- TestSum2[TestSum2$Group_Two == y_level,]
    lapply(unique(TestSum3$Group_Three), function(z_level) {
      TestSum4 <- subset(TestSum3, TestSum3$Group_Three %in% z_level)
      #TestSum4 <- TestSum3[TestSum3$Group_Three == z_level,]
      TestSum4 <- TestSum4 %>%
        group_by(Group_Four) %>%
        summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
        )
      TestSum4 <- arrange(TestSum4,desc(Quantity))
      Lvl4dfStatus <- tibble(name = TestSum4$Group_Four,y = TestSum4$Quantity)
      list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, z_level, sep = "_")), 
type = "column",
xAxis = 1, # 0 is the first type you put in the hc_xaxis argument, 1 is for the second, etc...
data = list_parse2(Lvl4dfStatus))
    })
  })%>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
}) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

After that, I modified the hc_xAxis argument to :

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(list(type = "category"), list(type = "datetime")) %>% # need to make a list for every type I wanted (first one is assigned 0, second 1, etc...
  hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F", xAxis = 0) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
  hc_drilldown(
    allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
    series = c(Level_2_Drilldowns_Test, Level_3_Drilldowns_Test, Level_4_Drilldowns)
  )
```

Note that I used a list for every type I wanted to assign to the X-axis. In this case, I assigned the value "category" to the first axis type (assigned 0 earlier) and "datetime" to the second axis type (assigned 1 earlier).

I hope this helps other users looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it! I learned something from this also

Comment: Thank you ! the more I read about "highcharts" the more I like it. Probably gonna be my main package for graphs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by modifying the code for Level_4_Drilldowns to use the dateTime x-axis and then updating the highchart function accordingly. To do this, you need to:

- Convert the date column to a numeric format (milliseconds since
  1970-01-01) in the Level_4_Drilldowns section.
- Add a new xAxis for the dateTime plot in the highchart function.
- Update the hc_drilldown function to include the xAxis update.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(highcharter)
    
    # Convert date to milliseconds since 1970-01-01
    Test$Group_Four <- as.numeric(Test$Group_Four) * 1000
    
    Level_4_Drilldowns <- lapply(unique(Test$Group), function(x_level) {
      TestSum2 <- subset(Test, Test$Group %in% x_level)
      lapply(unique(TestSum2$Group_Two), function(y_level) {
        TestSum3 <- subset(TestSum2, TestSum2$Group_Two %in% y_level)
        lapply(unique(TestSum3$Group_Three), function(z_level) {
          TestSum4 <- subset(TestSum3, TestSum3$Group_Three %in% z_level)
          TestSum4 <- TestSum4 %>%
            group_by(Group_Four) %>%
            summarize(Quantity = sum(Value)
            )
          TestSum4 <- arrange(TestSum4, desc(Quantity))
          Lvl4dfStatus <- tibble(x = TestSum4$Group_Four, y = TestSum4$Quantity)
          list(id = tolower(paste(x_level, y_level, z_level, sep = "_")), type = "column", data = list_parse2(Lvl4dfStatus))
        })
      }) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
    }) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
    
    highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(list(type = "category"), list(type = "datetime")) %>% # Add a new xAxis for the dateTime plot
      hc_add_series(Lvl1dfStatus, "column", hcaes(x = name, y = y), color = "#E4551F") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = "normal")) %>%
      hc_drilldown(
        allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
        series = c(Level_2_Drilldowns_Test, Level_3_Drilldowns_Test, Level_4_Drilldowns),
        activeDataLabelStyle = list(color = "#FFFFFF", textOutline = "none"),
        drillUpButton = list(theme = list(fill = "#E4551F", stroke = "#E4551F", r = 0, states = list(hover = list(fill = "#E4551F", stroke = "#E4551F"), select = list(fill = "#E4551F", stroke = "#E4551F"))), position = list(align = "right", x = -10, y = 10)),
        options = list(
          list(id = "root", xAxis = list(type = "category")),
          list(id = paste0(tolower(unique(Test$Group)), "_", tolower(unique(Test$Group_Two))), xAxis = list(type = "category")),
          list(id = paste0(tolower(unique(Test$Group)), "_", tolower(unique(Test$Group_Two)), "_", tolower(unique(Test$Group_Three))), xAxis = list(type = "datetime")) # Update the xAxis for dateTime plot
        )
      )
```